# throwing java.security.ProviderException: with KeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair() on Android 6.0 primarily

Tags: java, android, sqlcipher, android-security, key-pair

There has been a number of crashes on devices running Android 6.0 with the below exception. the key generation method is crashing with the below exception.keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair() method call is where it is happening.

```
*java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6320)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:221)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1860)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: 
  at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.generateKeyPair(AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.java:504)
  at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$KeyPairGeneratorImpl.generateKeyPair(KeyPairGenerator.java:276)
  at com.du.util.KeyStoreHelper.createKeysM(KeyStoreHelper.java:109)
  at com.du.util.KeyStoreHelper.createKeys(KeyStoreHelper.java:55)
  at com.du.util.KeyStoreHelper.getCipherPwd(KeyStoreHelper.java:242)
  at com.du.activity.DuApplication.initializeSQLCipher(DuApplication.java:272)
  at com.du.activity.DuApplication.onCreate(DuApplication.java:141)
  at com.du.activity.DuApplication_.onCreate(DuApplication_.java:21)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1036)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6317)*
```

Please find the code below, it is crashing at **keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair() method.**

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    static void createKeysM(String alias, boolean requireAuth) {
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
                    KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, SecurityConstants.KEYSTORE_PROVIDER_ANDROID_KEYSTORE);
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(
                    new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                            alias,
                            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                            .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(1024, F4))
                            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                            .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256,
                                    KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA384,
                                    KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                            // Only permit the private key to be used if the user authenticated
                            // within the last five minutes.
                            .setUserAuthenticationRequired(requireAuth)
                            .build());
            KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
            Log.d(TAG, "Public Key is: " + keyPair.getPublic().toString());

        } catch (NoSuchProviderException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're missing half the stacktrace

Comment: updated with the whole stacktrace